# Stuck inside this while loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection

Why is my `loginAuth` stuck inside the while loop?

I declared `connectionFinishLoading` as

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController {   
    BOOL connectionFinishLoading;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL connectionFinishLoading;

@implementation LoginViewController
@synthesize connectionFinishLoading;

 -(BOOL)loginAuth {

    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:myURL?id=%@&format=JSON", userName.text];
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestURL = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString]];
    loginConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestURL delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    [SVProgressHUD showInView:self.view status:@"Logging in"];
    while (!connectionFinishLoading) {
        NSLog(@"waiting..");
    }
     // code to executed after connection did finish loading.
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    [responseData appendData:data];
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    connectionFinishLoading = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you block the run loop and no packets are send over the network, thus the connection never finishes.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Which statement is blocking the run loop?

Comment: The while loop blocks the run loop.

Comment: Didn't I make an asynchronous connection, which will run on a separate thread? Or am I overseeing something? Basically, I want to continue performing some codes with the response data but don't want to do it inside `connectionDidFinishLoading:` delegate method.

Comment: You did asynchronous connection, which won't run on a separate thread.

Comment: I guess there's other easy way to do it other than doing it inside the `connectionDidFinishLoading:connection` method?

Comment: @MaTaKazer: A really really dirty way would be running the run loop inside of your while loop for a short period of time: `[[NSRunLoop currentRunloop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]]`(or something like this), but again, this is really dirty!

Comment: Yeah, I thought of something like that but its not very good as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
// A delegate method called by the NSURLConnection if the connection fails. 
// Production quality code would either display or log the actual error.
{
   #pragma unused(conn)
   #pragma unused(error)
   assert(conn == self.connection);

   NSLog(@"didFailWithError %@", error);

   connectionFinishLoading = YES;
}
```

But it is very bad practice to create such loops

Answer (score 0):

As JustSid mentioned, the run loop is being blocked. I would suggest getting rid of the "while" loop and BOOL connectionDidFinishLoading property, and then move your code to be executed into the connectionDidFinishLoading method. You should still handle the connection failed block some way too.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // code to executed after connection did finish loading.
}
```

Comment: Probably will do just for me as I don't make multiple connection. I was thinking if one had huge amount of different connections, it would be at a mess.